# MVC3 client side validation -- what am I missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I've googled, looked at blogs, checked out multiple answers here on SO... when I enable "Client Side Validation" in my MVC3 app, validation only takes place on the server, not the client -- my forms post with required text inputs that do not have values, only to be bounced at the server.

Full disclosure: I've never gotten this to work consistently and completely in any of the 3 MVC projects I've done so far. I'm convinced I'm missing something fundamental here, since the vast majority of the examples and how-to's I find carry "This article refers to beta release" disclaimers...

This is usually the point where I get frustrated and rip out all the "everything client side must be indirect and magic because we're afraid to have developers write javascript" garbage and just use jquery.validation directly, but I figured I'd try posting here to see if I'm missing something fundamental ... like I usually seem to be ;)

This Model:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

This view (the "textfield" classes are needed for styling):

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-item-right">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name is required.")
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new { @class = "textfield" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, "First Name")


        </div>

        <div class="form-item-right">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new { @class = "textfield" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, "Last Name")
        </div>

        <div class="form-item-right">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { @class = "textfield" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email, "Email Address")

        </div>

        <div class="form-item-right">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password, new { @class = "textfield" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, "Password")

        </div>

        <div class="form-item-right">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword)
            @Html.PasswordFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "textfield" })
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "Confirm")

        </div>

        <div class="form-item-right">
            <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!" class="buttonSignUp"/>
        </div>



}
```

This results in markup like:

```
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstName" data-valmsg-replace="false">First Name is required.</span>
            <input class="textfield" data-val="true" data-val-required="The FirstName field is required." id="FirstName" name="FirstName" value="" type="text">
            <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
```

These scripts included via a Layout view:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js") "type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this in web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Controller code for completeness:

```
    public ActionResult Candidate()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Candidate(RegisterModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //complete the registration

            return View("Confirm", new ConfirmationModel { Email = model.Email, FirstName = model.FirstName });   
        }
        else
        {
            return View(model);
        }
    }
```

All results in a view that does no validation on the client side. The form posts with no fields entered at all. Validation only takes place at the server (which works correctly FWIW).

What's wrong?

Edit to include resulting markup from the view.

Comment: Commenting to mention that, if I add "required" classes to the inputs in the view, and wire up validation directly via $("form").validate(), it prevents a post as it should, so the actual jquery part of this seems to be working.

Comment: Not being able to answer my own question is, frankly, bullshit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are doing wrong, but here are the easy steps you could follow:

1. Create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 project using the default template
2. Define the following model:

   ```
   public class MyViewModel
   {
       [Required]
       public string Foo { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. HomeController:

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
           return View(new MyViewModel());
       }

       [HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
       {
           return View(model);
       }
   }
   ```
4. Index view:

   ```
   @model MyViewModel

   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
       @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
       <button type="submit">OK</button>
   }
   ```
5. Run the project => client side and server side validation work as expected

Comment: Right. That's my problem. The trivial samples always work, but in a "real" app, it never works for me, despite following the same steps. And, frustratingly, the "magic" MVC stuff apparently isn't able to tell me what's gone wrong. I didn't include controller code since the server-side stuff is working, and it's not really relevant.

Comment: @lamont, well then try to include a complete and yet concise example of the source code allowing to reproduce the problem. You say that in a sample application it works but not in a real world. But you know that there are many different ways to write a real world application. And I cannot know which way you choose. For me it always works, even in complex real world applications. So if you expect help you will have to post a complete code illustrating the issue, the same way I did post a complete example illustrating that client validation works.

Comment: What do you consider missing from the example to make it "complete"? I've added controller code, though as I said, that's not relevant.

Comment: @lamont, well for example the controller code you have shown won't work. Your Candidate GET action doesn't pass any view model when you are returning the view. So you will get an exception.

Comment: @lamont, can you send me your project so that I can look at it and tell you what's wrong?

Comment: And FWIW, changing the controller to View(new RegisterModel()); does not force client validation to work.

Comment: Can't answer my own question for reasons of reputation, so I'll put this in a comment. Apparently deleting jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js and re-adding it from another made this work... for some reason. 
If anyone from the MVC team ever reads this, what would be REALLY nice is some way to debug why this "magic" validation is not working. Deleting and re-adding the same unversioned script file in hopes of getting things working is just not a good solution.

Comment: @lamont, maybe you were using some old version which is not compatible with jQuery 1.6.